# html css div element not showing up as I expect - following the tutorial

Tags: html, css

I was following this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaWN7gObv-c&t=23m46s) I reached about the time 23:46 and I'm not ending up with the same outcome. [image: screenshot from chrome element inspect]

Below is the html code I wrote - which I thought was exactly what he had in the tutorial, for some reason the div "pageTopWrap" is not contained in "pageTop", it seems that it's ending up underneath it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Teyta social network tutorial demo </title>

<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0px; }
#pageTop {
    background:url(style/headerSliver.png) repeat-x;
    height: 90px
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 90px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopLogo {
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    width: 108px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest {
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    width: 892px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest {
    height: 43px;
    background:#CCC;
    border:#F00 1px solid;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="pageTop"></div>
  <div id="pageTopWrap">
     <div id="pageTopLogo">
        <a href="http://www.teyta.com"> 
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" title="Teyta social network" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="pageTopRest">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div id="pageMiddle"></div>
<div id="pageBottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<div id="pageTop"></div>`

That is because you have not nested `pageTopWrap` inside `pageTop`.

Notice how you have created the div and closed it in the same line.

**Proper Nesting**

```html
<div id="pageTop">
  <div id="pageTopWrap">
    <div id="pageTopLogo">
      <a href="http://www.teyta.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="logo" title="Teyta social network" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="pageTopRest">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end #pageTop -->

<div id="pageMiddle"></div>
<div id="pageBottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The guy above is absolutely right. You must nest properly your conditions in CSS.
NOTE: I would prefer not having to use things like DOCTYPE and having a style tag. If you're watching a tutorial, you should add in a link rel tag so you can have more space when programming!

Also, why are you trying to make a menu at the tab, when you can just make a click-able link table with onMouse events? a lot cooler, quicker, and more code effiecient!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "make a click-able link table with onMouse events", I'm following a tutorial to learn some basic stuff, so I guess at some point I'll understand what you are talking about.